# Robot tests calling another robot file

Tags: robotframework

Is it possible to call a robot framework file from another robot framework file. Can some one give examples of it

**Requirement**

We have some tests which are of repetitive nature. The idea is to have these tests present in a Robot file which can be called into the main robot tests file. This will allow us to keep adding to the list of repetitive tests and all the new / old tests will be available for the main tests.

Any examples will help. Thanks.

-KK

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our SO Question Checklist to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Comment: Have you read the user guide? It has plenty of information regarding creating reusable keywords. Why do you need to repeat the exact same test more than once?

Comment: Lets say there are some negative events which are done in all our tests. In future because of SW upgrade another set of negative events are added to the existing tests. How do we take care of these situations.

Answer (score 1):

Tests (or Test *cases*) are not reusable components in robot framework. Tests exist to perform verifications. Once those verifications have been made, there's no point in running the test again in the same test run.

Even though tests can't call other *tests*, they can call *user keywords*, which is the foundation of robot framework. If you have bits of functionality that you want to be reusable, you put that functionality in keywords, and then you can use those keywords in as many tests as you want.

For example, lets say that you need to send a signal to a device and check for a light to come on. Instead of writing a *test* that does this, and then repeating the test over and over, you create a *keyword* that sends the signal, and a keyword that verifies the light is on, and then call these keywords from multiple tests (or one data-driven test).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. 
Just declare the file that you wish to call in **Settings** section of your code as specified below.

Resource          ../common/Resource_Apps.robot

Now you can use or call all the keywords written in this resource file.

Answer (score 0):

just import the another robot as a `Resource`

Settings:

```
Library    PythonLibrary.py
Resource   <Folder_Name>/Example.robot
```